# DynamoDB deny access to everyone but administrators and Lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I have several AWS Lambda functions, each one containing the following aliases (stages): **dev**, **qa** and **prod**.

Each of these functions have some environment variables which should have different values for each alias, but as setting environment variables on an alias level is not supported by Lambda, I've decided to use a DynamoDB table to store the variable values.

Now as these variables contains sensitive information, I would like to make sure that access to this table is as restricted as possible.

So I would like to deny access to everyone and only allow administrators and Lambda functions to access it.

I know that I may provide access to the table by using the appropriate roles/policies on IAM, but how may I make sure that access will only be provided to the users/functions for which I explicitly provided access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html) which is hierarchical and will allow you to set permissions per stage (example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-access.html)) or you can control based on tags (example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-access.html#sysman-paramstore-access-tag)).

Or you could package the parameters with the Lambda function upload.

For more ideas, see [this article](https://www.concurrencylabs.com/blog/configure-your-lambda-function-like-a-champ-sail-smoothly/).

Comment: Using the Parameter Store instead of saving sensitive information in a database is the right answer. Safer and easier to manage. Note that Parameter Store is part of Simple Systems Manager, so that's where you'll find it in the SDKs. For example, [Python SDK documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_parameter).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did read the article you mentioned, and based on it I've decided to go with DynamoDB. But I was not aware of Parameter Store, which seems like the perfect fit for what I'm trying to achieve (at least while there is no support for environment variables at alias level on Lambda functions).

Comment: [AWS Secrets Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/secrets-manager/) might also be a good option.

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger agree. This [post](https://www.1strategy.com/blog/2019/02/28/aws-parameter-store-vs-aws-secrets-manager/) has a comparison between Parameter Store and AWS Secrets.